# Update columns with two conditions or more SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column so that it is not 0 or null and that it supports any value > 0. I have posed this way but it does not work. I do not handle SQL very well yet and I do not see any clear example.

```
UPDATE TEST_MFE_AGRUP_PASARELA 
SET POLIGON = 0 
WHERE POLIGON > 0 AND POLIGON != 0;
```

Is it the right way?

Thank you guys!

Comment: This must be `WHERE POLIGON > 0 OR POLIGON !=0;`

Comment: If you use `WHERE POLIGON > 0` you wont include the case where `POLIGON=0`, so then you can remove the constraint `POLIGON!=0`

Comment: This can be simplified with WHERE poligon > 0 (is obvious that > 0 is not = 0)

Comment: `so that it is not 0 or null and that it supports any value> 0` ... this sounds like you want to alter the column datatype or add a constaint, not `UPDATE` the column values, but it is unclear.

Comment: Is your goal for the column to only contain items that are greater than zero (and not null)  after you run your query?  That's what your text sounds like to me, but your example code changes everything that is greater than zero to be zero.  (Also, I see the Oracle tag - are you *actually* using Oracle for this?  The syntax of the answer may well depend on which flavor of SQL you're using.)

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your result or why doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need check for null values. because `NULL > 0` return false.

The problem is `NULL <> 0` is also false so no rows get updated.

So you only need:

```
WHERE POLIGON > 0
```

Check this **[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/HDC61894)**

```
with tab(country, car, price) as ( 
    select 'Germany' ,'Mercedes', 30000 from dual union all
    select 'Germany' ,'MERCEDES', 30000 from dual union all
    select 'Germany' ,'BMW'     , 20000 from dual union all
    select 'Germany' ,'Opel'    , 15000 from dual union all
    select 'Japan'   ,'Honda'   , 20000 from dual union all
    select 'Japan'   ,'Toyota'  , NULL from dual
)
select country, car, price
from tab
WHERE price > 15000
```

Comment: I would say that `NULL>0` evaluates to `UNKNOWN` which is not `TRUE` and row is omitted by `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @lad2025 You are correct, but the effect is the same isnt?

Comment: Yes, effect will be the same. I just wanted to point it out. It may be misleading when you use this kind of syntax with `CHECK` constraint or with `WITH CHECK OPTION` on view. Funny things may happen :)

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand you.
As I understand you want to assign a value to the field Poligon if that field is 0 (zero) or null (empty). If that is the case your where-statement should be    `WHERE POLIGON=0 or POLIGON IS NULL`

Comment: `POLIGON != 0` should be equivalent to `POLIGON IS NOT NULL`